# What are good replacements for "in this case"?

Tags: synonyms

Scenario:

- We have multiple pages, each representing a different concept.
- Each concept has an image.
- We have some text below the image. The text talks about the specific context, but it's not matching exactly to the image (the image is generic, the concept is more specific).

Example:

- Concept and image used: game (general).
- Specific concept: specific game.

Original sentence:

> In this case [meaning in this concept], it is the game XYZ.

What is a good replacement for "in this case"?
I want to use somethng **more specific**, than in "in this case"

Comment: You explain why you need an alternative for "in this case". Is it simply that you want to avoid repetition or is there something about "in this case" that doesn't work for you in this example?

Comment: I want to use somethng more specific, than in "in this case"

Comment: But it's probable you want to specify the actual example (within the set of actual games) that you've chosen, rather than emphasise 'within this set'. The latter only makes sense, as far as I can see, if you've grouped individual games into subsets.

Comment: To discuss the concept of gaming, we’ll look at the game XYZ.

Comment: Someone's downvoting was not explained. This is a reasonably defined question from a newcomer, and it should be welcomed. I do so.

Comment: @Anton I disagree and if I knew how, I'd have down-voted it… At best, the Question belongs somewhere like Writing and that's not here…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I agree that it is on the edge of acceptability but surely we should extend a little latitude to a newcomer, as constantly suggested by the site? If we reject folk immediately rather than educate them we run the serious risk of deterring for ever rather than attracting long-term participants.

Comment: @Anton Fine but here, what could really be 'more specific' than 'in this case'? Simply seeking synonymous phrases might deserve that latitude but seeking something more specific than one of the best-known phrases designed to be specific seems to me to belong to some combination of Writing or Learning, not Usage.

I plan to restrain myself from further comment.

Comment: Hey everyone. I use English daily but I like variety and I think more specific = clear to the reader. I am trying to understand what are common ways to state the same sentence. In fact I provided an example, but I am open to many different interpretations as long as they shed some light how to make more specific some "overused" words. I think like anything language is a learning process that is faster when multiple contexts are considered, so perhaps in that extent, would have it been more accurate to ask for free interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

> This section is the XYZ concept.

or

> These pages describe the concept of the XYZ game.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also write as

> Here, it is the game XYZ.